# How many headers are attached to voice data when we use VoIP services?

Tags: voip

How many headers are attached to voice data  when we use VoIP services?

What I understand is, the maximum number of headers that can be attached to voice data is 4.

For example, Layer-2 would add a Frame-header. At layer 3, Frame-header would be removed and then IP-header, UDP-header and VoIP-protocol-headers would be attached sequentially.

Am I correct?

Comment: Don't keep changing the question. You need to ask a new question if the answers to your original question cause you to have more questions. The Help Center provides some guidelines to writing a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked about a packet, which is a layer-3 construct, it will not contain any layer-1 or layer-2 information, but it will be contained in layer-2 frame(s) in transit across the layer-1 medium/media.

There will be a protocol header for the packet itself, and there may, or may not, be a layer-4 segment with a protocol header. Those one or two protocol headers are the extent of the network protocol headers in the packet.

After that, it is completely up to whichever application originates the payload data to determine if there are any other headers, which ones, and what they may be.  Application-specific headers have nothing to do with network transport, and their use (or very existence) varies from application to application. This subject is normally beyond the scope of what is discussed on this site.

A study of the OSI model may be useful, but just remember that it is a model that doesn't necessarily reflect the real world, especially when it comes to the layers above layer-4.

The number of headers in packets containing VoIP data is dependent on the VoIP application being used. In the context of a single VoIP application, the answer to you last question is probably, "Yes," but different applications may, or may not, have a different number of application headers. To the network, VoIP is just another payload (application).

Comment: Well, Skype uses a proprietary data format over UDP, so you do have the IP and UDP headers that carry the Skype payload. If you are interested in how Skype formats its data (really beyond the scope of this site) you can find out a lot more with a simple Internet search which returns sites like this: https://github.com/matthiasbock/OpenSkype/wiki/Skype's-UDP-Format

Comment: If you are speaking of packets which are layer-3, then you have a layer-3 header, and possibly a layer-4 header if a layer-4 protocol such as UDP is used. My point is that the application may, or may not use headers; that is completely application dependent. You could have as few as one header for the packet, and that's all, or your application may have any number of headers. There is no one answer; each application may, or may not have what you call a header, and certainly the application "headers" have nothing to do with the network or transportation of the payload across the network.

Comment: I think what is confusing you is that there is no standard network payload for VoIP, like there is with HTTP, that can tell you what the payload of a packet carrying VoIP looks like. Each VoIP application is free to use the network (layers 1 to 4) to transport any data format which the application programmers sees fit to use.

Comment: The VoIP data format is defined by the VoIP application. That's what I have been trying to tell you. That is why you have to jump through so many hoops to get VoIP data originating on one VoIP application to be able to be used in a different VoIP application. Browsing is easy since just about everybody who creates HTTP servers and HTTP browsers uses the same set of standards. VoIP is not like that. There are various VoIP standards for signalling and encoding the data, but the way an application formats with "headers" varies from application to application.

Comment: We can't use this as a chat session since it wasn't designed that way. If you want to chat, then you should use the chat room; there is usually somebody monitoring it. This is going to be shut down since we have exceeded what is really allowed for comments. If you don't like the answer then don't vote for it or accept it. I tried to answer your original question, but you kept changing the question after it was answered, and that is bad form. If you really want an answer to a question different than what you originally asked, you need to start a new question.